# Хранение копии YouTube видео в Telegram-е

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Как через Telegram бот хранить копию YouTube видео в Telegram-е? Не скачать, а именно сохранить видеофайл в самом Telegram-е. Желательно вместе с названием и описанием. Я понимаю что для ботов ограничение на размера файла 50 Мб, некоторые видео попадают в этот лимит.

Вопрос возник потому что на Youtube попадается интересное видео, которое ты хочеш посмотреть позже. Ты добавляешь его в плейлист "Смотреть позже". Потом заходиш в этот плейлист, а его уже нету! Только надпись "Недоступные видео скрыты".

Я понимаю что есть сервисы репостеры на другие видео сервисы. Но у них тоже удаление зависит от администрации сервиса, а не от пользователя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел такого бота https://t.me/SY_legal_info

Пробовал сохранять длинные видео по 45 минут. Правда не знаю долго ли будет хранить, только сегодня шашел.